# Can't change Python version, wamp server

Tags: php, python, wamp

I'm using Wamp on Windows to host a server.

this is my php script to run a python script:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('script.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

This is my Python Script to check ver.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

The print is == 3.0.1 (r301:69561, Feb 13 2009, 17:50:10) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

The problem is i can't install pip,setup tools and requests on 3.0.1 .

So, i need to change the version to Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49)

i've tried to use "#!C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe"
as shebang but, no effect. It keeps printing 3.0.1.

Any way to change the Python version that is running the script?

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is use a path to python before the path of .py script

Example:

$output = shell_exec('path\to\python path\to\script.py');